# How to get RTL css in bootstrap 3.2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gruntjs

The bootstrap 3.2 was released yesterday. It was announced to have rtl support in this release. I checked their doc and site, cannot find anything, however in the release log, they did mention Switch to grunt-css-flip Grunt plugin for RTL CSS generation.

Does that mean I have to use this grunt plugin to generate rtl css, if yes, can someone teach me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RTL support got removed again prior to v3.2.0's release. See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/f5513fd30ef16228869b1ec3473217dab63f2c29

Here's some background:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13564#issuecomment-44230448

Comment: I just saw that thread, this is the most disgusting thing I ever saw.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a little bit late but it seems that there is a handy css file for that made by [Morteza](https://github.com/morteza) which can be found here: https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl

I've tested it and so far, it's working just as expected. Even if you will find a minor problem, you can report than or even better, fix it yourself and fork that.